# How to use cookie to sign in using prompt

Tags: javascript, cookies, case, prompt

Hi I would like to create a prompt that uses cookies like [w3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_cookie_username). I would also like to add a feature which I created.

```html
     

                   <body onload="checkCookie();deny()">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //This code has been copied from w3 schools link
        function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays){
        var date=new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires="expires="+date.toGMTString();
        document.cookie=cname+"="+cvalue+";"+expires+";path=/";}
        function getCookie(cname){
        var name=cname +"=";
        var decodedCookie=decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        var ca=decodedCookie.split(';');
        for(var i = 0; i<ca.length; i++){
        var c=ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' '){
        c=c.substring(1);}
        if (c.indexOf(name)==0){
        return c.substring(name.length,c.length);}}
        return "";}
        function checkCookie(){
        var user=getCookie("username");
        if (user!=""){alert("Welcome again "+user);} 
        else{
        user=prompt("Please enter your name:");
        if (user!=""&& user!=null){
        setCookie("username",user,30);}}}
        //The below code I would like to integrate in the code above
        function deny(){
        var sign=prompt("Please enter your name?");
        sign=sign.toLowerCase()
        var hi="Hi! ",we=" we are processing.",yes="Access allowed.",no="Access denied."
        switch(sign){
        case "Bla","bla":
        alert(hi+"Bla"+we)
        alert(yes)
        break;
        case "":
        alert("You have not entered a name!")
        break;
        default:
        alert(hi+sign+we)
        alert(no+"Sorry we don't recognize you!")}}</script>
        </body>
```

[Working example on fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blablablogblag/gbmp8dfy/)

Can you please tell me how to combine both of these `functions` so I get a result like this:

1. First `onload` I want a prompt to appear that functions like the second prompt in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blablablogblag/gbmp8dfy/) which has a "?" At the end.
2. I would like the input that is given in the second prompt be processed with the `deny()` function I created.

3.Only if the in put is "bla" then only it should be saved as a cookie and should be redirected to some link.
4.if the input is not "bla" it should redirect it to `javascript:void(0);`